# Not working SetCredentials on VBA

Tags: vba, excel, http

I want to send HTTP Get request on VBA using WinHttp but I have a problem with Basic Authentication.
here is my code .

```
Dim hReq as Object
Set hReq = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
Dim api as String
api = "https://api.pinbet88.com/v2/sports/"
hReq.SetCredentials "aaaa","gfddfg",0
hReq.send
```

but not working with SetCredentials.
Please help me on this.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

please add this to your code: "hReq.Open "GET", api, False"

```
Dim hReq As Object
Set hReq = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
Dim api As String
api = "https://api.pinbet88.com/v2/sports/"
hReq.Open "GET", api, False
hReq.SetCredentials "aaaa", "gfddfg", 0
hReq.send
```

Comment: I want to request API with GET method.

Comment: by mistake I wrote Post, I have fixed it

Comment: I've tried that , but working , did you tried that before ?

Comment: pm me to help , yunaandvann@yahoo.com

Comment: I tried with no error, but I don't know if it is run correctly on the specific page...I will give you a link to a tutorial....